# Application design in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, rcp

What are the plug-in conventions you use in your big Eclipse RCP-applications?
Should ui and code-behind be separated, or is it enough to separate the different parts of the program into plug-in-projects?
What about the database-connection? Should this be one plug-in as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest convention is making product releasing and patching even more simplier. For example, if there is a bug in plugin.A, the fixing and patching are only plugin.A related changes, instead of the whole product rebuilding and distributing.

The best practices could be learned from well-known eclipse projects plugin organization, like CDT, or other projects. However, the requirements from your application are the most important.